# Vuetify data table doesn't get the updated array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuetify.js

I populating the Vuetify data table with some user data. When I remove a user from the data table I update the user array like this:

```
handleDelete(user) {
  confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user?") &&
    axios
      .delete("user/" + user.id)
      .then(response => {
        // Delete user from user array
        this.users = this.users.filter(function(el) {
          return el.id != user.id;
        });
      })
},
```

When I register a new user the array is also updated but now like this:

```
handleRegister(user) {
  axios
    .post("user/register", user)
    .then(response => {
      // Update User array
      this.users.push(response.data.user);
    })
},
```

This all works fine, except when I update a user. In my function I search for the user object in the array of users and replace it for the updated one. But somehow the data table don't get updated with the new values. The update function looks like this:

```
   handleUpdate(user) {
      const id = user.id;
      axios
        .put("user/" + id, user)
        .then(response => {
          // TODO: Update User array
          let foundIndex = this.users.findIndex(
            x => x.id == response.data.user.id
          );
          this.users[foundIndex] = response.data.user;
        })
    },
```

When I `console.log` the values of `this.users[foundIndex]` and `response.data.user` it shows me the right values. But somehow it seems like the data table doesn't get updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently fixed it by writing this function:

```
updateUserArray(user) {
  // Look for the index of the user
  let index = this.users.findIndex(
    x => x.id == user.id
  );

  // Remove the user from the array
  this.users= this.users.filter(function(el) {
    return el.id != user.id
  });

  // Add the updated value to the array
  this.users.splice(index, 0, user);
},
```

Seems like I had to use the splice function because this forces the DOM to refresh while directly updating the array doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

i think its problem with scope of "this" variable.

```js
// it should be like this below
handleDelete(user) {
  const _this_0 = this;
  confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user?") &&
    axios
      .delete("user/" + user.id)
      .then(response => {
        // Delete user from user array
        _this_0.users = _this_0.users.filter(function(el) {
          return el.id != user.id;
        });
      })
}
```

```js
handleRegister(user) {
  const _this_0 = this;
  axios
    .post("user/register", user)
    .then(response => {
      // Update User array
      _this_0.users.push(response.data.user);
    })
},
```

```js
handleUpdate(user) {
      const id = user.id;
      const _this_0 = this;
      axios
        .put("user/" + id, user)
        .then(response => {
          // TODO: Update User array
          let foundIndex = _this_0.users.findIndex(
            x => x.id == response.data.user.id
          );
          _this_0.users[foundIndex] = response.data.user;
        })
    }
```

Comment: That returns an `undefined`

Comment: sorry i dont understand. what returns undefined?

Comment: '_this_0' is undefined

Comment: ok. then i think it not problem with ur code. but u need to manual refresh dom to update vue data tables. if you use splice it forces dom to refresh. check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52613517/why-is-vuetify-data-table-not-updating-correctly)